# The "CollectBundleResources" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm newbie to learn xamarin. When i download sample and build but I got error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "CollectBundleResources" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build403214 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.0.3.214/copy-item/SamplyGameiOS/25940bb/CoreData.pak ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/niennguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/SamplyGameiOS/25940bb6fa00542affd423f61b9739d0/D:/SamplyGame/packages/UrhoSharp.1.0.410/build/Xamarin.iOS10/../../native"
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) <0x19fb700 + 0x00148> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) <0x19fb4f0 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Handlers.CopyItemMessageHandler+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0 () <0x33203b8 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <0x1935f30 + 0x00051> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x1935780 + 0x0004d> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x188f5d0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188cf00 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce60 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce10 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x188d3c0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Handlers.CopyItemMessageHandler+<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext () <0x3320000 + 0x00253> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x188f5d0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188cf00 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce60 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce10 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x188cde0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`1+<HandleAsync>d__5[TMessage].MoveNext () <0x331f780 + 0x0035b> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x188f5d0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188cf00 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce60 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce10 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x188d3c0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`1+<<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__3>d[TMessage].MoveNext () <0x331f110 + 0x00257> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x188f5d0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188cf00 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce60 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce10 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x188cde0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient+<>c__DisplayClass36_0`1+<<ReplyAsync>b__0>d[TRequest].MoveNext () <0x331eba0 + 0x0011b> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x188f5d0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188cf00 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce60 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x188ce10 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x188d600 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient+<ReplyAsync>d__34`2[TRequest,TResponse].MoveNext () <0x31f70e0 + 0x00383> in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 188
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__22`2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__26`2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 306
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IMessagingClientExtensions.Execute(Action postAction) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\IMessagingClientExtensions.cs:line 231
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IMessagingClientExtensions.Post[TRequest](IMessagingClient client, TRequest request, Boolean retain, Int32 timeoutSecs) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\IMessagingClientExtensions.cs:line 195
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Build.BuildClient.UploadItem(String path) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Build\BuildClient.cs:line 99
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Build.TaskRunner.CopyRequiredInputFiles(Task task) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Build\TaskRunner.cs:line 219
   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.CollectBundleResources.Execute() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks\Tasks\CollectBundleResources.cs:line 14
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SamplyGame.iOS
```

Comment: try to "rebuild all" while the mac is connected

Comment: i tried but it didnot work. i use vs 2015 on Windows and MAC on VMWare.

Comment: Can you give more information on what sample you've downloaded?

Comment: From https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples